# How I keep a horizontal unordered list from breaking?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a list of thumbnails that I can scroll horizontally, but it breaks no matter what I do.

This is what I have now

http://jsfiddle.net/EXCf3/

```
ul{
    width: 100%;
     list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
li{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` on the `ul`:

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

<kbd>[Demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/EXCf3/4/)</kbd>

**Explanation:**

I used the `white-space` property because it gives me the potential to handle what to do with the white space left in the object so I said it to make no wrap of that white space occuring the `ul` and display all of them in one line.

Answer (score 1):

use nowrap

```
ul {

white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
list-style-type: none;
margin: auto;
overflow-x: scroll;

   }
```