# How can I prevent my ul list from breaking line? [duplicate3 - still cannot find the solution]

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a dynamic user interface that puts together model attributes by its category.

One of the problems is that I need to put other runtime attributes on this screen. What I want to happens is everytime I add an attribute, or a new category, it keeps appending on the display list horizontally and it shows up a horizontal scroll bar.

Every time I add an attribute, the layout does not do what I want, and it gets all "fuzzy".

I then did some research on StackOverflow and I got this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725591/how-i-keep-a-horizontal-unordered-list-from-breaking), which is exactly what I wanted.

So, I decided to apply it, but no success. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

First, this is the html.

```
<fieldset class="GPP21KJDHK" style="">
    <legend>Victim</legend>
    <div class="GPP21KJDLK" style="overflow: auto; position: relative; zoom: 1;">
        <div style="position: relative; zoom: 1;">
            <div class="GPP21KJDMK" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                <div class="horizontal">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="vertical">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img class="GPP21KJDPL" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-b...151332.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: auto;">
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                            <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">Given Name</div>
                                            <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">XXXX</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                            <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">Last Name</div>
                                            <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">XXXXX</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="horizontal">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <fieldset class="GPP21KJDLL">
                                            <legend>PersonalVehicle</legend>
                                            <div class="GPP21KJDML">
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">Personal Vehicle</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">Palio</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">Personal Vehicle Color</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">White</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">I'm adding</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">lots of stuff</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">XXX</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">yyyy</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <fieldset class="GPP21KJDLL">
                                            <legend>MedicalData</legend>
                                            <div class="GPP21KJDML">
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">Known problems</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">??</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">Known problems</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">??</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">Known problems</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">??</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">KK</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">yyyy</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">I'm adding</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">lots of stuff</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">I'm adding</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">lots of stuff</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <fieldset class="GPP21KJDLL">
                                            <legend>PhysicalProfile</legend>
                                            <div class="GPP21KJDML">
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">I'm adding</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">lots of stuff</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">I'm adding</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">lots of stuff</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">I'm adding</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">lots of stuff</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">I'm adding</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">lots of stuff</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">I'm adding</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">lots of stuff</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">Eye Color</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">marrom</div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="GPP21KJDOL">
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDNL">Age</div>
                                                    <div class="gwt-Label GPP21KJDAM">23</div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Then, I tried the following CSS (both without success)...

```
.GPP21KJDOL {
padding-bottom: 10px;
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
page-break-inside: avoid;
break-inside: avoid;
}

.GPP21KJDLL {
border-style: none;
background-color: red;
}

.vertical {vertical-align:top; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%;}
.vertical > ul {list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; width:100%;}
.vertical > ul > li {display:block; text-decoration:none; margin:0px; padding:0px 0px;     overflow:hidden;}
.horizontal {padding:0px; margin:0px; width:100%; height:inherit;}
.horizontal > ul {float:left; list-style:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; width:100%;}
.horizontal > ul > li {float:left; display:block; text-decoration:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

and

```
.horizontal {padding:0px; margin:0px; width:100%; height:inherit;}
.horizontal > ul { width: 100%; list-style-type: none; margin: auto; overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap;}
.horizontal > ul > li {float:left; display: inline-block;; text-decoration:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
horizontal {padding:0px; margin:0px; width:100%; height:inherit;}
.horizontal > ul { width: 100%; list-style-type: none; margin: auto; overflow-x: scroll; white-space: nowrap;}
.horizontal > ul > li {float:left; display:block;; text-decoration:none; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out a bug on Chrome. The code works fine.